# Using orWhere clause makes my model get all the data instead only related data

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm getting only the items of a single category, I have 148 items in my DB and when I'm trying to filter the related data, when I use the `orWhere` clause in the query I get all items instead of only related ones. I'm loading temporary items and non-temporary items (it is possible that a temporary item has its listed date already expired, that's why I use the `orWhere` clause). However, if I remove the `orWhere` clause I receive only the temporary items because those are the only ones that have a date in those fields, but at least is doing a correct filtering that doesn't happen with `orWhere`

```
$products = Itemcategory::where('id', $id)->first()->items()
            ->select('items.id', 'items.itemName', 'items.itemCode', 'items.itemDescription', 'items.itemSaleprice', 'items.unitary_cost', 'items.mu_id', 'items.itemCoverimage', 'items.headquarter_id', 'items.itemWeb', 'items.min_sale_quantity', 'items.time_limit_to_order')
            ->whereDate('listed_since', '<=', now()->format('Y-m-d'))
            ->whereDate('listed_until', '>=', now()->format('Y-m-d'))
            ->OrWhere([
                ['listed_since', null],
                ['listed_until', null]
            ])
            ->where([
                    ['active', '=', true],
                    ['itemWeb', true],
            ])->count();
```

Comment: Please read [this](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#logical-grouping). Note > You should always group orWhere calls in order to avoid unexpected behavior when global scopes are applied.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than looking through the `ItemCategory` records to grab the record with the provided `id` then looking through its `items`, I would query for `items` where they belong to the required `ItemCategory`.

I've made an assumption about the name of your relationship between the `ItemCategory` and `Item` being `category`.

```php
$items = Item::whereHas('category', function ($query) use ($id) {
    $query->where('id', $id);
})->where(['active' => true, 'itemWeb' => true])
  ->where(function ($query) {
    $query->whereDate('listed_since', '<=', now()->format('Y-m-d'))
        ->whereDate('listed_until', '>=', now()->format('Y-m-d'))
        ->orWhere(['listed_since' => null, 'listed_until' => null]);
});
```